# How to disable text-highlight for prompt default text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prompt

I have a prompt like this:

```html
<button onclick="prompt('Enter the URL', 'http://')">click</button>
```

As you see, when that window opens, `http://` is highlighted ..! Now I want to disable it. In other word, I want when that pop-up window shows, `http://` doesn't be selected. How can I do that?

Comment: This is controlled by the browser itself at a level lower than JS has access to. You can't change this behaviour.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see. thanks

Comment: There are custom (CSS/JS) prompts and alerts out there on the web, which can be customized.